# Why do I have both of these constructors in my class?

Tags: c#

In my project, I see that I have two constructors.  The debugger only ever attaches to the second constructor - why do I have both?

```
public EventDialog()
{
    // Required for Windows Form Designer support
    InitializeComponent(); 

    m_timer.Interval = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
    m_timer.AutoReset = false;
    m_timer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapseCallback);
} // Constructor

public EventDialog(string[] list)
{
    // Required for Windows Form Designer support
    InitializeComponent(); 

    if(list != null)
    {
        foreach(string s in list)
        {
            if(s.Trim() != string.Empty)
                m_leafComboBox.Items.Add(s.Trim());
        }
    }

    m_timer.Interval = SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime;
    m_timer.AutoReset = false;
    m_timer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapseCallback);
}
```

Comment: Then in it is the 2nd contructor being called by the code - ie find the code thatr actually constructs an EventDialog and it will use the 2nd one it the debugger steps into that one. As mentioned below the default (paramterless) constructor is required for the VS designer.

Comment: Your statement "debugger is attaching through only second constructor" is not clear.  Not sure what you are referring to.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: You can also simplify the second contructor by saying: `public EventDialog(string[] list) : this()` and eliminate the duplicated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that only the second constructor is attached is that there must exist a call which passes a value to the constructor and the second constructor does not call the parameterless constructor. If you define a constructor with parameters, it will be the only constructor that is accepted. I.e., a parameterless constructor will no longer exist on the class. However, if you want to continue to allow other code to instantiate the class using a parameterless constructor and you want a constructor with parameters, you must declare both.

Answer (score 3):

```
     //
     // Required for Windows Form Designer support
     //
```

Only the comment in the first constructor is accurate.  You can't design the form without a default constructor.  Make it look better like this:

```
  public EventDialog(string[] list) : this()
  {
     if (list != null)
     {
        // etc..
     }
  }
```

Note the added this() to call the default constructor.  You now only have to add the special constructor code.

Comment: So you meant only one constructor is sufficient like this?

Comment: Only the first *comment* is correct.  Delete it from the 2nd constructor.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter-less constructor (the first one) is required because otherwise Visual Studio designer won't be able to create an instance of this class (I suppose that's a Form class) to show in in the UI designer.

The second constructor is most probably created by a developer to pass some extra parameters when creating the dialog manually from code.

BTW I'd better write it like this:

public EventDialog(string[] list) : this()
{
...
}

Comment: invoking default constructor using this isnt technically correct as the extra code is insterted between code in the default constructor. Granted in this situation it looks like it wouldnt create a bug, but that is not the case genereally... only if additional code would go below all statements in the default constructor.